# nvm windows installation of node getting stuck on "Extracting..."

Tags: node.js, nvm-windows

I installed the latest nvm Windows cli tool; and when I try to run `nvm install lts` it shows "Downloading..." then "Extracting..." and freezes there. Never errors, but never moves on, either. If I kill the process and do `nvm list`, it lists 16.15.0. But if I say `nvm use 16.15.0`, or `nvm uninstall 16.15.0`, it says it isn't installed.

I've tried uninstalling nvm and starting over from scratch; same result every time. How do I get past 'Extracting'?

[image: Screen shot of command prompt stuck on Extracting]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok this was a bizarre problem and solution.

Looks like my (work) laptop had previously had win-zip or 7-zip installed, but when it was uninstalled, it didn't re-associate zip files with Windows Explorer.

That meant that the option to click Extract All on a zip file, even manually, was grayed out/disabled. I followed the instructions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/extract-all-is-greyed-out-on-windows-10-windows/b54f6c83-e7be-4928-98ac-6728fb2cf1d8): to re-associate .zip files with Windows Explorer:

> START menu > Settings (the cog) > Apps > Default Apps. Scroll to the bottom
> of that list and look for "Choose default apps by file type". Then
> scroll down that until you find ".ZIP" make sure the default is
> selected to "Windows Explorer".